# Using Otsu's Method to separate water and not-water in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1, flood

I am trying to separate permanent waterbody and not-water from Sentinel-1 image in earth engine. To do this I am taking a median and mean image for a month from a range of years and then using Otsu's threshold to get a threshold to separate the two classes.

```js
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[92.214, 24.121],
    [92.214, 25.165],
    [91.006, 25.165],
    [91.006, 24.121],
    [91.006, 24.121]], null, false);
Map.centerObject(roi);

// Function to get all the images for a month for a set year
var jan = function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 31);
    var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
    return filtered;
};

var jul = function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 7, 1);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 7, 31);
    var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
    return filtered;
};

// Otsu's Method

var otsu = function(histogram) {
  var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
  var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
  var size = means.length().get([0]);
  var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var mean = sum.divide(total);
  
  var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
  
  // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
  var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
    var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        .divide(aCount);
    var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
    var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
    return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
           bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
  });
  
  print(ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array(bss), 0, means));
  
  // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
  return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'), ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select('VV');

var years1 = ee.List.sequence(2015, 2022); // As Sentinel-1 Was launched in April 4, 2014. Some months only have data from 2015
var years2 = ee.List.sequence(2014,2022);

var janCollection = years1.map(jan);
var julCollection = years2.map(jul);

var all_jan = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(janCollection).flatten());
var all_jul = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(julCollection).flatten());

var median_jan = all_jan.median().clip(roi);
var median_jul = all_jul.median().clip(roi);

Map.addLayer(median_jan, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'median_jan', 0);
Map.addLayer(median_jul, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'median_jul', 0);

var mean_jan = all_jan.mean().clip(roi);
var mean_jul = all_jul.mean().clip(roi);

Map.addLayer(mean_jan, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'mean_jan', 0);
Map.addLayer(mean_jul, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'mean_jul', 0);

var threshold_func = function(image) {
  var histogram = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
  geometry: roi, 
  scale: 10,
  bestEffort: true
  });
  //print('DEBUG HIST', histogram);
  
  var plot_hist = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: image,
  region: roi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  print('Histogram', plot_hist);
  var threshold = otsu(histogram.get('VV_histogram'));
  print('s1 threshold', threshold);
  
  var water = image.lt(threshold).selfMask();
  return water;
};

var jan_water = threshold_func(median_jan);
var jul_water = threshold_func(median_jul);

Map.addLayer(jan_water, {palette: 'blue'}, 'Jan Water', 0);
Map.addLayer(jul_water, {palette: 'blue'}, 'Jul Water', 0);

var jan_water_mean = threshold_func(mean_jan);
var jul_water_mean = threshold_func(mean_jul);

Map.addLayer(jan_water_mean, {palette: 'blue'}, 'Jan Water Mean', 0);
Map.addLayer(jul_water_mean, {palette: 'blue'}, 'Jul Water Mean', 0);
```

Here's the link to the code too: https://code.earthengine.google.com/efd45e08fed2b79dec04605f79e385fd

The method seems to work pretty well for the month of July, but It's performance is not good in January. It's a lot more noisier. Furthermore, in the mean image there's a line in the middle possibly because that's where two images from sentinel-1 joined in this area of interest.

How do I overcome the problems?

Answer (score 1):

The Sentinel 1 images are noisy on the sides. A quick and dirty fix is to mask based on the angle band. You might have to play with the min/max angle based on your ROI. I'd also switch to a `calenderRange()` filter. It's simpler, and probably a bit more performant.

```
var maskBorder = function (image) {
  var minAngle = 30.88
  var maxAngle = 45.35
  var angle = image.select('angle')
  var sideMask = angle.gt(minAngle).and(angle.lt(maxAngle))
  return image.updateMask(sideMask)
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'), ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')))
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('orbitProperties_pass', ['ASCENDING', 'DESCENDING']))
    .filterBounds(roi)

var all_jan = collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 1, 'month'))
  .map(maskBorder)
  .select('VV')
var all_jul = collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7, 7, 'month'))
  .map(maskBorder)
  .select('VV')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/05e317c5473ec353a5fccceffe664d2c

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the maskBorder function? I am having trouble understanding the minAngle and maxAngle determination.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S1_GRD#description: `Each scene also includes an additional 'angle' band that contains the approximate incidence angle from ellipsoid in degrees at every point. This band is generated by interpolating the 'incidenceAngle' property of the 'geolocationGridPoint' gridded field provided with each asset.`. It allows you to roughly identify the areas with potentially bad data. Add the angle band of an S1 image to the map to see how it looks and inspect to find some reasonable angle thresholds.

Comment: Different regions require different angles - it unfortunately require a bit of a trial and error. Remove too much and you get gaps in your composite. Remove too little and you don't remove all bad data.